# Cannot import cloudinary in nodeJS with "navigator undefined" error

Tags: node.js, react-native, backend, cloudinary

I recently installed cloudinary via npm and cannot import it in my nodeJS backend due to the following error.

```
(base) feiwu@Feis-MacBook-Pro backend % node server.js        
/Users/feiwu/projects/inventaire/backend/node_modules/cloudinary-core/cloudinary-core.js:1168
var useAgent = navigator && navigator.userAgent || '';
               ^

ReferenceError: navigator is not defined
    at Module../src/namespace/cloudinary-core.js (/Users/feiwu/projects/inventaire/backend/node_modules/cloudinary-core/cloudinary-core.js:1168:16)
    at __webpack_require__ (/Users/feiwu/projects/inventaire/backend/node_modules/cloudinary-core/cloudinary-core.js:37:30)
    at /Users/feiwu/projects/inventaire/backend/node_modules/cloudinary-core/cloudinary-core.js:101:18
    at /Users/feiwu/projects/inventaire/backend/node_modules/cloudinary-core/cloudinary-core.js:104:10
    at webpackUniversalModuleDefinition (/Users/feiwu/projects/inventaire/backend/node_modules/cloudinary-core/cloudinary-core.js:10:20)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/feiwu/projects/inventaire/backend/node_modules/cloudinary-core/cloudinary-core.js:17:3)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:708:14)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:887:19)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:74:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/Users/feiwu/projects/inventaire/backend/node_modules/cloudinary/lib/utils/index.js:48:57)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:999:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1027:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:863:32)
```

I have found nothing so far about this error and would like to know if someone know about this issue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cloudinary had just released a new version to its [JS SDK](https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js) (version 2.12.2) that fixes this issue.

Answer (score 3):

This error is from cloudinary's end. Fix this error with npm i cloudinary-core.

Answer (score 3):

Started happening to me around 15 hours ago as well.

Answer (score 1):

installing cloudinary-core helped me get rid of this error

```
npm i cloudinary-core
```

Answer (score 1):

This issue was introduced recently in Cloudinary version `1.28.0.`
https://www.npmjs.com/package/cloudinary/v/1.28.0

The issue reported on github here : https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_npm/issues/524

I was able to fix this issue by pointing cloudinary to 1.27.1

```
"cloudinary": "1.27.1"
```

Cloudinary guys have fixed this issue here : https://github.com/cloudinary/cloudinary_js/pull/281.